# OOP PHP - GET the form post

Tags: php, forms, oop, post

Hello I'm watching a tutorial about OOP PHP "How to make login form". And I can't understand how the form post was gotten from this code.

input.php

```
class input
{
  public static function exists($type = 'post')
  {
    switch ($type)
    {
        case 'post':
            return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
        break;
        case 'get':
            return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
        break;
        default:
            return false;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

register.php

```
if (input::exists())
{
  //the submit button was clicked
}
```

So I will be happy if someone explain how does that work and how can i specify it to a specific form. Like this.

```
if ($_POST['specific submit name'])
{
  // the specific submit button was clicked.
}
```

Comment: How to say thanks for an answer is to upvote and mark it accepted!

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
public static function exists($type = 'post')
  {
    switch ($type)
    {
        case 'post':
            return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
        break;
        case 'get':
            return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
        break;
        default:
            return false;
        break;
    }
  }
```

checks if the `$_POST` or `$_GET` superglobal arrays are empty. So let's say that you need to check if a POST requests has reached your page. You call `input::exists('post');` That means the first case is true and this part of the code will be executed:

`return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;`

This code returns `true` if `$_POST` is **not** empty, which practically means there's data in it or `false` if it is empty. Truth be told, this statement could be more easily written like this:

`return !empty($_POST);`

The if/else logic is pretty reduntant as is most of that code. To check if a particular value is in the `$_POST` array you can use `isset`.

So let's say you submit a form or send an AJAX request and one of the fields has a name of 'foo', you can check if 'foo' exists in `$_POST` like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['foo'])
{
    //do something with foo
}
```

As you can see there are simpler ways to check if `$_POST` is populated and with what values. As I said above I consider the `input` class and the `exists` method reduntant code. You could use this tutorial just for learning what OOP is but I wouldn't rely on it